# Data doesn't get written into a file in C

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to input data into a `DATA` file, read it and write even and odd numbers in `EVEN` and `ODD` files respectively.

I wrote the below code to take input from user and store it in `DATA` file. Then check whether the number is even or odd by reading it. If the number is even then the number gets added in `EVEN` file else it gets added in `ODD` file.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

FILE *DATA, *EVEN, *ODD;
int number, i;

printf("Enter Contents of the DATA file\n\n");
DATA = fopen("DATA", "w");

for(i = 1; i<=30; i++){
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number == -1) break;
    putw(number, DATA);
}
fclose(DATA);

DATA = fopen("DATA", "r");
EVEN = fopen("EVEN", "w");
ODD = fopen("ODD", "w");

while((number = getw(DATA)) != EOF){
    if((number % 2 == 0)) putw(number, EVEN);
    else putw(number, ODD);
}

fclose(DATA);
fclose(EVEN);
fclose(ODD);

fopen("EVEN", "r");
fopen("ODD", "r");

printf("\n\nContents of EVEN file\n\n");
while((number = getw(EVEN)) != EOF) printf("%4d", number);

printf("\n\nContents of ODD file\n\n");
while((number = getw(ODD)) != EOF) printf("%4d", number);
}
```

The above code doesn't give out any odd numbers. Where did my code went wrong?

> Output:

[image]

Comment: `fopen("EVEN", "r");` --> `EVEN = fopen("EVEN", "r");`, the same with "ODD".

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych Oh! Thanks. I got it. But why do you think it gave output  for my code, at least then `EVEN` file? When I change the order of those print statements, it still gave output for `EVEN` file only.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour after `fclose`

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych please post as answer!

Comment: @sidyll I'm not considering this to be an answer - this is just maybe a typo in code (because `DATA` was reopened correctly). If you, or anyone else want - feel free to post this an answer.

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is 1: in your logic (EVEN test should be number %2 == 0), also you need to set the file pointers when you reopen the files here is the fixed code: (I recommend also checking when the files are opened and closing them when they're done.)

```
void main() {

    FILE *DATA, *EVEN, *ODD;
    int number, i;

    printf("Enter Contents of the DATA file\n\n");
    DATA = fopen("DATA", "w");
    if (DATE == NULL)
    {
        // some error
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &number);
        if (number == -1) break;
        putw(number, DATA);
    }
    fclose(DATA);

    DATA = fopen("DATA", "r");
    EVEN = fopen("EVEN", "w");
    ODD = fopen("ODD", "w");
    if (DATE == NULL || EVEN == NULL || ODD == NULL)
    {
        // some error
    }

    printf("\n\nData File Contains:\n");
    while ((number = getw(DATA)) != EOF) {
        if ((number % 2 == 0)) putw(number, EVEN);
        else putw(number, ODD);
        printf("%4d", number);
    }

    fclose(DATA);
    fclose(EVEN);
    fclose(ODD);

    EVEN = fopen("EVEN", "r");
    ODD = fopen("ODD", "r");

    printf("\n\nContents of EVEN file\n\n");
    while ((number = getw(EVEN)) != EOF) printf("%4d", number);

    printf("\n\nContents of ODD file\n\n");
    while ((number = getw(ODD)) != EOF) printf("%4d", number);

    printf("\nPressAnyKey\n");

    fclose(EVEN);
    fclose(ODD);
}
```

Comment: `putw(number, (number % 2) ? ODD : EVEN);`